# different "no content" message based on taxonomy vocabulary/term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

how would I change the message:
"There is currently no content classified with this term"
when viewing a term that doesn't have conent asscociated with it?

I see the message is in taxonomy.pages.inc and that I could just edit that line, but that would change it for ALL terms, whereas I'd like to have a custom message based on the taxonomy vocabulary.

Lets' say I have vocabularies:
"countries" message > Sorry no event listed in [country-name]
"sports" message > Sorry no games of [sport-name]

Please keep in mind I am not a coder.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 has a default Taxonomy Views display you can use to override the default pages.  Here are the steps:

1. Install Views, if you haven't already.
2. Go to Structure -> Views and look for the **Taxonomy term** view.
3. In the little button that says "Enable", drop it down and select
   "Clone", and create a new name for the view (it defaults to "Clone
   of Taxonomy term").  This will make a copy of the Taxonomy view.
4. Edit the view, and drop down the Advanced tab.  Add a NO RESULTS
   BEHAVIOR.
5. Select Global: Text area.
6. Enter the text you want to display for no results.

Let me know if you need help beyond this.

Comment: Thank you. That removes even the terms that do have content associated with them, and it gives same message for all vocabulary. Apologies if I have not been clear, I need to change the text only when there is no content associated with the term, and custom text for each vocabulary.

Comment: Can you clarify "that removes even the terms that do not have content associated with them"?  I'm not sure what you mean by that.  When there is no related content, does your custom message display?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I mean that I get the custom message for all terms, ones with content associated, and the ones without content; in all vocabularies, and all terms I get the custom message; whereas I want custom message for each vocabulary. i.e. vocabulary > country (terms list of countries), if no content message should be: Sorry no events in Italy; vocabulary > audience (list of target audience), if no content message should be: Sorry no events for youth. And so on.